# Haskell isMember function error

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

```
isMember:: a -> [a] -> Bool
isMember y [] = False
isMember y (x:xs) =
 if y == x then
  True
 else
  isMember y xs
```

Trying to create a function that will identify whether something is a member of a list. For example:

```
isMember 6 [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>True
```

However I keep getting a complier error stating 'no instance for (Eq a) arising from the use of '=='

Help would be appreciated (I'm new to Haskell & Recursion in functional languages so explain like I'm five.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you are almost there

```
isMember :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
isMember _ [] = False
isMember y (x:xs) =
 if y == x then True else isMember y xs
```

What the compiler tells you that you promised to accept any type of list members - but later you use the function `==` which is not available for all types (for example functions).

By adding `Eq a =>` you say I accept all input which have an equals method.

### Some additional notes

You can (re)write the last line as

```
isMember y (x:xs) = (y == x) || isMember y xs
```

which is equivalent to your implementation (thanks @chi for the comment).
What is nice about your version is that it is tail recursive.

Another point to note - the pattern:

- return something for empty list case (`isMember _ [] = False`)
- and iterate over the list with this value (`isMember y (x:xs) = ...`)

happens to turn up a lot and has been abstracted into the family of `fold` -functions (`foldl`, `foldr` ...). Putting it in your use case it looks like

```
isMember y xs = foldl False (\x b -> (x == y) || b) xs
```

Comment: Since `||` is lazy, I'd consider the alternative to be, in all aspects but syntax, tail recursive. Its execution has essentially the same space and time of the tail recursive one.

Comment: Why did you change `||` to `&&` in the `foldl`?

Comment: @4castle - because I had it copied from the wrong section in my ghci session, I tested it in order to have no incorrect code - but then copied the wrong part. - updated

Comment: I think starting the second section with "Alternatively" could be a bit confusing, since it sounds like you're saying rewriting the last line is an alternative way to solve the OP's problem. It's actually just extra advice; they'll need to add `Eq a` anyway. Would something like "Additionally" be a better lead in?